# Threading using Kivy to read serial and get user input at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, kivy, pyserial

I am making a controller that updates labels continuously from a vacuum pump by sending commands through serial. This controller also takes user input to start and stop the vacuum. I have gotten it to work, however my problem is the timing seems to be off. At the beginning of the program the buttons are responsive, however after running for a couple minutes it seems the schedule_interval() function seems to overpower the user input response based on serial output, and the button output lags significantly and all pile up at the end when I terminate the program. (As a note, I am using a Raspberry Pi to send serial. I don't know if there are any device limitations I need to consider as well.)

```
Clock.max_iteration = 20

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
ser.timeout = 1            #non-block read
ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
ser.writeTimeout = 2     #timeout for write

Builder.load_file('MyApp.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):

    def Button1(self):
        #read serial 
        #write serial 
        #update labels

    def Button2(self):
        #read serial 
        #write serial 
        #update labels

    def Button3(self):
        #read serial 
        #write serial 
        #update labels

    def exitButton(self):
        print("Program terminated")
        exit()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()  
 

    def on_start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.updateLabels).start() #thread    
        #Clock.schedule_once(self.updateLabels, 1)
  
    
    def updateLabels(self, *args): #this function updates labels
        #write serial for label 1
        #read serial for label 1
        #update label 1 

        #write serial for label 2
        #read serial for label 2
        #update label 2

        #write serial for label 3
        #read serial for label 3
        #update label 3                
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.updateLabels, 2) #update labels every 2 seconds 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ser.open()

    except Exception as e:
        print("error opening serial port: ") 
        exit()
    if ser.isOpen():
        try:
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.flushOutput()
        except Exception as e:    
            print("Error communication") + str(e)
    else: 
        print("Error communicating")
    MyApp().run()
```

Output example:

```
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Write Command: Button1  
Write Command: Button2  #proceeds to lag after
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Write Command: Button2 #this button would have been pressed 30 sec ago
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Update Data: label1
Update Data: label2 
Update Data: label3 
Write Command: Button1 #piles up at the end after 3-5 mins unresponsive
Write Command: Button1  
Write Command: Button2  
Write Command: Button1  
Write Command: Button1  
Write Command: Button2  

Program terminated #takes at least 15 sec for this to actually terminate program
```

I tried to use threading in order to allow both functions to run at the same time. However, it seems they interfere with reach other. My goal would be to have the buttons on the responsive at any time while the program is running, but the labels to be updated continuously every 2 seconds or less (if possible).

Comment: I've not used that framework, but is it possible your `Clock.schedule_interval` call is adding a new timer each time?  That would explain all the updates. Move that call into `on_start` and see what happens.

Comment: @RufusVS, The `Clock.schedule_interval` call in my `updatesLabels` function calls itself every 2 seconds and the function sends serial to the vacuum pump and receives and updates the values on the controller display. This is great, but when I press a button, it seems that the program is too busy running the `updateLabels` function and does not deal with the button press until way later. If I call the `Clock.schedule_interval` call in `on_start`, the program will crash. If I call it once in `on_start`, the program will ignore button press. I tried threading but it doesn't work well.

Comment: I believe @RufusVS is correct. Try replacing `Clock.schedule_interval()` with `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: @John Anderson I did as instructed and used `Clock.schedule_once()`. The buttons are now responsive, but unfortunately `updateLabels()` is only called once & no more. How could I stop the function `updateLabels()` in the event a button is pressed and have it resume after the button pressing event is finished? I apologize if I sound redundant, I don't have much coding experience.

Comment: Since you haven't posted your `kv` file, I cannot test your code. But, your `on_start()` method runs `updateLabels()`  once in another thread. If you use the `Clock.schedule_once()` inside the `update_labels()` method, then every time `update_labels()` is run, it will schedule itself to be run again in another 2 seconds.

Comment: generally, you should put your serial code in function that runs in a separate thread.  use queue.Queue objects to pass information into and out of that thread and you can also use threading.Event object to block or pass True/False like states.  these objects are both thread-safe.  Create those objects in main and pass them also into the threaded function and then you have them available in both.  I use Raspberry Pi to do very similar things and with many many serial peripherals.  it can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your `update_labels()` method should be run on the main thread, not in another thread, since it is modifying the GUI. One solution is to modify the `on_start()` method like this:

```
def on_start(self):
    # threading.Thread(target=self.updateLabels).start() #thread    
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.updateLabels, 2)
```

This will run `update_labels()` on the main thread every 2 seconds. Since that handles the scheduling, you can eliminate any use of `Clock.schedule...` inside the actual `update_labels()` method.

If the internals of your `update_labels()` method takes too much time, this approach will interfere with the responsiveness of your app. If that is the case, then you will need to run a different method in another thread where the time consuming code is run, but the `Labels` are not updated. That code can then use `Clock.schedule_once()` to schedule a method that does nothing but change the `Label` texts.